# Android: Listview not showing any results

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have included my code to help clear things up. Basically I have two screens on my app, one will display a list, and the other will allow the user to add a new item to that list. Eventually I will incorporate database data to save the list view, but I do not require help with that. I have not yet coded the second screen, so I have not included the code for it.

The problem is that I cannot get the list view to display. I have even tried adding data to the array through code, with no luck. Can anyone see a problem here?

Issues.java

```
public class Issues extends Activity {

    public static ArrayList<String> strArray;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public static ListView serieslistview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.issues);

        strArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        Button btaddnewseries = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        serieslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //opens the add new series menu
        btaddnewseries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ComicIssues.this, AddSeries.class);
                Issues.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        strArray.add("Item One");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);

        serieslistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

issues.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="+"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:text="Issues"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have only shared the method to create the data, where is your effort to fetch from DB.

Comment: I have not created the database yet. I am simply trying to show data from the array at the moment

Comment: Then where are are you trying to extract a list from an array, you have also not shared your code to display the list on screen

Comment: Yeah, there is no indication of anything wrong with the shown code... But that doesn't mean that there is nothing wrong. There is... Perhaps you have wrong imports... Sometimes the most simplest mistakes are the hardest ones to find.

Comment: I just ran the code, it works fine for me.

Comment: I execute your code. its working and show one item in list view.you can change text color and try it.your device may have different styling.

Comment: Not sure whats going on guys. I've just deleted the list view and added a new one and still getting nothing. Do I have to extend ListActivity to use a list view? Changed the text to black and still have nothing :(

Comment: No, leave your code as is, it works.  Something else is going on.  Check the logs.  What do you see, just a blank screen?  Do you see the `+` button in the upper right of the screen?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, just noticed that too! No all the other items are showing as normal on the screen, and no log information that seems out of the ordinary. Thanks though!

Comment: So you already tried replacing `ComicIssues.this` with `Issues.this`?  If so I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Yeah I've already fixed that up, and still not luck with the list view. Thanks though Daniel! Ill delete your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I can't see any problem in your code. I will give you two things I have noticed.

1)Instead of listing your data into an `ArrayList` use `String[]`

2)You don't have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you first give the `adapter` the input data. Only when you change the list of data later after. So instead of re-initialize the adapter, just call `notifyDataSetChanged`

Give this code a try and let me know if you still have a problem.

```
public class Issues extends Activity {

public static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
public static ListView serieslistview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.issues);

    Button btaddnewseries = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    serieslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //opens the add new series menu
    btaddnewseries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ComicIssues.this, AddSeries.class);
            Issues.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

String[] values = new String[] { "Item 1", 
                                         "Item 2",
                                         "Item 3",
                                         "Item 4"
                                        };

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,values);

    serieslistview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

And use this .xml instead of yours

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="+"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Issues"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've taken them on board, but still not showing any items. Hmmm

Comment: What is showing right now? can you see the `Button` or the `TextView`

Comment: Yeah I can see the textview and the button correctly. I am thinking there may be something wrong with the xml code?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Ok, Clean the project then Build it again and try. Then let me know

Comment: No need to use a `String[]`, that's sort of going backwards since you can't resize it.  It works fine with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks Sami, just gave your xml a go and still showing no ListView or any items in the list view

Comment: Try to remove everything in the XML except the listview to make sure that it is not a problem of widget confection @timbats1993

Comment: Post the whole activity, because you might be hiding it somewhere else @timbats1993

Comment: Fixed now! Basically had to re-create everything. Not sure what the problem was, I just copied and pasted my old code. Strange. Thank you for your help

Comment: @timbats1993 you are welcome, get used on those wierd stuff specially with Eclipse, I recommend you strongly to move to Android Studio. Thanks for accepting the answer and I would be grateful if you vote my answer up as I voted urs, cause I see an effort it :)